# Caliburn.Micro collection is shown as empty

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to show the content of a `Collection` using *Caliburn.Micro* but, for some reasons, there's no output on the screen.

Here's the code:

(SearchView.xaml)

```
<ListBox x:Name="Items">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

(SearchViewModel.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace MyNS.ViewModels
{
    public class SearchViewModel : Screen
    {
        private BindableCollection<string> _items;
        public BindableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set
            {
                _items = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
            }
        }

        private string _selectedItem;

        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedItem);
                MessageBox.Show(value);
            }
        }

        public SearchViewModel()
        {
            Items = new BindableCollection<string>
            {
                "item1",
                "item2",
                "item3",
                "item4"
            };
            DisplayName = "by genre";            
        }
    }
}
```

While the logger prints

> [2013-12-16T21:52:29.9208275+01:00] SelectedItem binding applied to Items.
>   [2013-12-16T21:52:29.9208275+01:00] Binding Convention Applied: Element Items.

which means that everything went fine, I still don't get why my `ListBox` shows with no data.

No exception is thrown, everything runs smooth but the data is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a number of issues doing custom `ItemTemplate` with Caliburn Micro. So instead, whenever I use one, I just use the `ItemSource` binding:

```
<ListBox ItemSource={Binding Items}>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn `Caliburn.Micro` just because it looked so smooth, without the need of manually binding stuff, but I guess that this is a situation in which there's no other way to make it work :\

Comment: @StepTNT It's great if you want to do very generic things. If you want a lot of custom stuff, it's best to not use it.